# Flutter Array subscript is not an integer

Tags: ios, swift, flutter

For some reason, I've started getting this when I issue the Flutter run command, I'm unsure if something has updated in the background.

```
Semantic Issue (Xcode): Property 'userInfo' not found on object of type 'UNNotification *'
/Users/martyn/FlutterDev/flutter/.pubcache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-9.4.0/ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.m:156:36


Semantic Issue (Xcode): Array subscript is not an integer
/Users/martyn/FlutterDev/flutter/.pubcache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notificztions-9.4.0/ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.m:156:44
```

I'm also getting a number of deprecated from

```
/Users/martyn/FlutterDev/flutter/.pubcache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_local_notifications-9.4.0/ios/Classes/FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.m:335:4:

warning: 'UILocalNotification' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - Use UserNotifications
    Framework's UNNotificationRequest [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
    - (UILocalNotification *)buildStandardUILocalNotification:
```

I don't know how to resolve it.
Thank you

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to include all relevant code in the form of a [mcve] in order to make the question on-topic.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by running flutter pub cache repair